# FIle transfer over a JMX method

Tags: file, jmx, transfer

I have a method exposed in a MBean in server. Now, i have to call this method from the client and transfer a file to the server. How do i do it?

Regards,
Al Niyas

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on what this remote method looks like, but what I would recommend for this operation is to have the JMX Server expose a method like:

```
void transferFile(String fileName, byte[] content)
```

Your local client can read the local file, read in all the bytes into an array and then pass the file name and the byte array content as arguments to the JMX Server method.